# Tarjan's articulation point algorithm on strongly connected graph

Tags: tarjans-algorithm

I have been studying [Tarjan's articulation points finding algorithm](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) and it says that the root node is an articulation point if it has more that 1 child. But if the graph is strongly connected, the root node shouldn't be an articulation point even if it has more than 1 child. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a graph is strongly connected then its root will never have 2 child.
Remember , we are talking about DFS tree here. Hence in strongly connected graph , DFS-tree's root will only have one child and thats for sure.Try it urself.

Comment: yes, you are right! I forgot to visualize the dfs tree. Thanks!